# Android AsyncTask is not updating Progress Bar

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kotlin, android-progressbar

Hello I have a problem with asynctask.I play a song then I update duration to progressbar. But when I play a new song progressbar don't back to 0th position and progressbar is continuing with old value
Here is my code:

```
class Task(context: Context, progressBar: ProgressBar) : AsyncTask<Int, Int, String>() {
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private var progressBar: ProgressBar? = progressBar
private var count = 0
override fun doInBackground(vararg input: Int?): String {
    while (count <= input[0]!!) {
        count++
        publishProgress(count)
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        if (isCancelled){
            count=0
        }
    }
    return "Task completed"
}

override fun onPreExecute() {
    progressBar!!.progress = 0
}

override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: Int?) {
    progressBar!!.progress = values[0]!!
}
}
```

when I play song :

```
    override fun onItemClicked(position: Int, song: Song) {
    val secondsDuration = song.duration!! / 1000
    activity!!.pgbSong.max = secondsDuration
    val task = Task(context!!, activity!!.pgbSong)
    if (task.status == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
        task.cancel(true)
    }
    task.execute(song.duration)
}
```

Comment: Please try to improve community and accept the answer from @Demigod if it solved your issue.
Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 2):

Well, what to say - you never cancel previous async tasks. Cause you're calling `cancel(true)` on just created async tasks every time:

```
val task = Task(context!!, activity!!.pgbSong)
if (task.status == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
    task.cancel(true)
}
task.execute(song.duration)
```

Instead, you should save previous async task in an object variable (something like this):

```
private var asyncTask : AsyncTask<*,*,*>? = null
```

And after in the method call:

```
override fun onItemClicked(position: Int, song: Song) {
    if (asyncTask.status == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
        asyncTask.cancel(true)
    }

    val secondsDuration = song.duration!! / 1000
    activity!!.pgbSong.max = secondsDuration
    asyncTask = Task(context!!, activity!!.pgbSong)
    asyncTask.execute(song.duration)
}
```

And, I guess, you should do a `return` in an `AsyncTask` when you're checking if it canceled or not.

But please don't use `AsyncTask` in this manner. Cause it holds links views and activity which can prevent those of being garbage collected and so cause a memory leak.

And please don't use `!!` with Kotlin. Instead use `null` check or provide default value if `null`. Examples:

```
val int = object?.int ?: 0
val context = activity ?: return
val view = activity?.pgbSong ?: return // or if (view != null)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Im newbie in kotlin